# Function to determine the direction of an arrow

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function in a project that I feel could be written better. The purpose of the function is to return the direction of an arrow based on two parameters.

- **`positiveDirection`**: The direction for a positive result. The values could be `increasing` or `decreasing`.
- **`changeType`**: Whether the result was `positive`, `negative` or `no-change`.

I guess it's the `if` statement that is bothering me the most; it looks like it could be reduced based on some logic gate that I don't know of.

```js
  getArrowDirection = (positiveDirection, changeType) => {

    let direction = null

    if(changeType === 'no-change') {
      return direction
    }

    if(
        (changeType === 'positive' && positiveDirection === 'increasing') ||
        (changeType === 'negative' && positiveDirection === 'decreasing')
      ) {
      direction = 'up-arrow'
    } else if(
        (changeType === 'positive' && positiveDirection === 'decreasing') ||
        (changeType === 'negative' && positiveDirection === 'increasing')
      ) {
      direction = 'down-arrow'
    }

    return direction
  }
```

Comment: What's possible values for `changeValue` and `positiveDirection`?

Comment: We might be able to improve the code further if we knew the context. Who calls this code, and where do the parameter values come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `changeValue` can only be (after your early check for '`no-change`') equal to 'positive' or 'negative' and `positiveDirection` can only be equal to 'increasing' or 'decreasing, your `if` should cover all possible ways.

But you can simplify it a lot making use of the xor operator:

```
 direction = (changeType === 'positive' ^ positiveDirection === 'decreasing')
             ? 'up-arrow'
             : 'down-arrow';
```

Or make the whole function a one-liner:

```
return (changeType !== 'no-change')
       ? ((changeType === 'positive' ^ positiveDirection === 'decreasing') ? 'up-arrow' : 'down-arrow')
       : null;
```

Comment: This is slick. Definitely a better solution than my original code. The ^ syntax was something I didn't know about.

Comment: Given `A^B`, if `A` and `B` are either both `true` or `false`, returns `false`. Otherwise, returns `true`. If fact, you can also replace it with `!=` but I found the logic xor prettier/smarter :)

Answer (score 4):

The test for `if(changeType === 'no-change') {` is redundant and not needed as it will fall through if the other tests fail and return `null` anyways.

You could also break the statement up returning the result as needed and falling through if they fail for `null`.

```
const getArrowDirection = (dir, type) => {
    if (type === "positive") {
        if (dir === "increasing") { return "up-arrow" }
        if (dir === "decreasing") { return "down-arrow" }
    }else if (type === "negative") {
        if (dir === "increasing") { return "down-arrow" }
        if (dir === "decreasing") { return "up-arrow" }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Assuming that you have given all possible values you can make assumptions and reduce the code further

```
const getArrowDirection = (dir, type) => {
    if (type !== 'no-change') {
        if (type === "positive") { return dir === "increasing" ? "up-arrow" : "down-arrow" }
        return dir === "increasing" ? "down-arrow" : "up-arrow";
    }
    return null; // returning null is not the best. Returning undefined would
                 // be better and would not need this line
}
```

You can use an object as a lookup using the combined strings.

```
const getArrowDirection = (() => {
    const directions = {
        positiveincreasing: "up-arrow",
        negativedecreasing: "up-arrow",
        positivedecreasing: "down-arrow",
        negativeincreasing: "down-arrow",
    };
    return (dir, type) => directions[type + dir] ? directions[type + dir] : null;
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

We don't need the `direction` variable - we can simply return at the appropriate point.

Once you know that `changeType` is one of `'positive'` or `'negative'` and that `positiveDirection` is either `'increasing'` or `'decreasing'`, you can test whether the two equality tests match:

```
// Winging it, because this isn't my language!
getArrowDirection = (positiveDirection, changeType) => {

    if (changeType != 'positive' && changeType != 'negative') {
        return null;
    }
    if (positiveDirection != 'increasing' && positiveDirection != 'decreasing')
        return null;
    }

    if ((changeType === 'positive') == (positiveDirection === 'increasing')) {
        return 'up-arrow';
    else
        return 'down-arrow';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could could extract your conditions into functions with very clear condition description names. Would cut down the code because many of those conditions are repeated.